# obiect doesn't work properly when class is imported

Tags: python, opencv

I have 4 modules in my folder (one is *init*.py) xml file and separate album for pictures.

I have 
main.py

```
from zdjecia import pics

pic = pics()
pic.run()
pic.end()
```

zdjecia.py

```
import cv2
import time
import threading
import os
from facedetect import detektuj


class pics (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        self.camera_port = 0
        self.ramp_frames = 30
        self.camera = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_port)
    def get_image(self):
        retval, im = self.camera.read()
        return im
    def run(self):
        for i in xrange(self.ramp_frames):
         temp = self.get_image()
        mon = 1
        while mon <100:
             camera_capture = self.get_image()
             file = os.path.dirname(__file__)+ "/nazdjecia/test_image"+str(mon)+".png"
             if(cv2.imwrite(file, camera_capture)):
                 detektuj(file)
                 time.sleep(0.2)
                 mon+=1
             else:
                 print "camera problem"
                 self.camera.release()
                 break

    def end(self):
        self.camera.release()

pic = pics()
pic.run()
pic.end()
```

and finally facedetect.py

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')
eye_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_eye.xml')

def detektuj(path):
    img = cv2.imread(path)
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        roi_color = img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
        eyes = eye_cascade.detectMultiScale(roi_gray)
        for(ex,ey,ew,eh) in eyes:
            cv2.Rectangle(roi_color,(ex,ey),(ex+ew,ey+eh),(0,255,0),2)
    print faces
```

if I run zdjecia.py everything is just fine, but if I try to start from the main.py it goes to the zdjecia, runs and than breaks and says "camera problem".

Why does the problem occur only when I start from main?

Comment: Not sure, but when you run from main, you actually run your zdjecia.py code *twice*, and imwrite maybe fails when trying to overwrite an image

Comment: @deets This. Remove the duplicate lines from `zdjecia.py` (last three lines) and it should work fine.

Comment: Can you post the full traceback?  While the module-level calls are obviously a problem, it's hard to tell if they're _the_ problem.  The traceback will tell you (and us) exactly which module, class, method, and line is failing and why.

Comment: Also, a typical Python program has an `if __name__ == '__main__':  main()` block at the bottom to avoid exactly this kind of confusion.  Once you've added that block, create a new `main` function and move your module-level `pic = ...` code into it.  Your script will still run from the command line just like before, but the `if` block will allow you to `import` the module without it running God-knows-what.

Comment: nope the problem was "os.path.dirname(__file__)" somehow it returned nothing do the whole path crashed, now it works like charm, thx guys.